# Fedora 23 password only showing 5 characters. Issues using su command

Tags: fedora, su

Today I installed Fedora 23, and once I finished I had no problems the SU command. I rebooted my VM and logged in, and it wont let me use the SU command. When I enter it, it asks for my password. So I enter it, and it say invalid password. So I checked my account settings and it only shows 5 characters. What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

The password length in the user account dialog *always* shows five dots (•••••) ***regardless of actual length of password***. Otherwise, this would be an information leak, making it (theoretically) easier for an attacker to brute-force or otherwise guess your password.

[image]

Note, though, that the `su` command is looking for the **root** password. You may not have even set one during install, if you set up your account as an administrator. In that case, use `sudo`, which will give root-equivalent access using your own password.

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is to change your password, making it at least as long as the minimum password length required by Fedora.  After that, you should be able to use that password in `sudo`.

The change to the minimum length was discussed early this year in LWN *[Fedora and "strong" passwords](https://lwn.net/Articles/631522/)*, indicating that this would be **8** characters.  If you change your password (and still too short), the system should tell you.  But you can check the minimum length by looking at `/etc/login.defs`.  Under Fedora 22, this *was*

```
PASS_MIN_LEN    5
```

For further information see the manual page for [login.defs](http://linux.die.net/man/5/login.defs).

Comment: I cant exactly change it because i dont know what the 5 digit password is, and when I use mine it doesnt work